How do I loop something forever in JS?
I am trying to loop this block of code. How do I do that? I am trying to change the color forever.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script  defer  src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 onclick="changecolor()">HackerXGames</h1>
  </body>
</html>



function changecolor(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#800000";
          setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0066";
            setTimeout(() => {
              document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff6699";
              setTimeout(() => {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#9900cc";
                setTimeout(() => {
                  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "Lime";
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000099";
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ff9430";
                     },1500)
                   },1500)
                 },1500)
               },1500)
             },1500)
           },1500)
         },1500)
       },1500)
     },1500)

   },2500)
  }


It would be much smarter to put all of the colors in an array and cycle through them in your loop.

@ColemanTO That will block the page completely.

Use setInterval() to run code periodically. The function can increment the array index.

Just add another changecolor() call in the last (innermost) setTimeout callback

Use setInterval if you want something to loop endlessly at a continuous rate.
The function returns an ID for the interval, so if you want to stop it at a later time, you can call clearInterval with that ID.


const colors = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'lightblue',
    '#800000',
    '#ff0066',
    '#ff6699',
    '#9900cc',
    'Lime',
    '#000099',
    '#ff9430',
];

let colorInterval;
let colorIndex = 0;

function startChangingBg() {
    changeBackground(); // This is optional; so you don't have to wait for first interval
    
    colorInterval = setInterval(changeBackground, 1500);
}

function stopChangingBg() {
    clearInterval(colorInterval);
}

function changeBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex += 1;
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script  defer  src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HackerXGames</h1>
    <button onclick="startChangingBg()">Start changing background</button>
    <button onclick="stopChangingBg()">Stop changing background</button>
  </body>
</html>




Maybe try something like this.
// keep a list of all the colors you want to cycle through
const colors = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'lightblue',
    '#800000',
    '#ff0066',
    '#ff6699',
    '#9900cc',
    'Lime',
    '#000099',
    '#ff9430',
];

// this function sets the color
const changeColor = (color) => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

// keep track of the color you are on
let colorIndex = 0;

// this function waits for an amount of milliseconds
const sleep = async (millis) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });
};

// main function
(async () => {
    // loop forever
    while (true) {
        // sleep for 1500 ms
        await sleep(1500);
        // change the color
        changeColor(colors[colorIndex]);
        // update the color index
        colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length;
    }
})().catch(console.error);


Function doesn't need to be marked async, if it just returns a promise.

@gre_gor That’s technically true, but it’s good practice to mark promise-returning functions as async. I always follow this eslint rule. It helps you ensure that you always call catch() on your promises.

You can use the setInterval function in combination with an array of colours.


const colors = ["blue", "red", "lightblue", "#800000", "#ff0066", "#ff6699", "#9900cc", "Lime", "#000099", "#ff9430"];
let index = 0;
let intervalId;

function changecolor() {        
    if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId); 
    }

    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
        index = (index + 1) % colors.length; // This will loop back to the first color after the last one
    }, 1500);
}
<h1 onclick="changecolor()">HackerXGames</h1>



This code will continuously cycle through the colors in the array indefinitely, changing the background color every 1.5 seconds.
